# Parent window not updating from child window in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I am updating a parent window from a child window using javascript and Coldfusion, it works in IE11, but not in Microsoft Edge:

When a user selects a location from the child window, the parent window needs to be updated with this information. I have verified that I am getting the 'rdata' (child window data) correctly, I think the problem is with var 'applyTo', but I don't know how to make this work in Edge.

```
function updateParent(id) {
    var applyTo = top.frames['<cfoutput>#session.dialogWinId#_ifrm</cfoutput>'].parentFormName;
    var topwindow = top.frames['<cfoutput>#session.dialogWinId#_pfrm</cfoutput>'];
    var rdata= jQuery('#LocationSearchGrid').jqGrid ('getRowData', id);

    applyTo.origin_code.value = rdata.apc_code.toUpperCase();
    applyTo.origin_country_code.value = 
    top.cf.Trim(rdata.country_code).toUpperCase();
    applyTo.origin_city.value = rdata.city_name.toUpperCase();
    applyTo.origin_state_province.value = rdata.state_prov_code.toUpperCase();                
    applyTo.origin_postal.value = rdata.postal_code.toUpperCase();
    applyTo.origin_beyond_point.value = rdata.best_available_svc_code.toUpperCase();
    locationType = "";
}
```

error received:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin_code' of undefined
> at updateParent line 97

which is this one:

```
applyTo.origin_code.value = rdata.apc_code.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Try `console.log(top.frames['<cfoutput>#session.dialogWinId#_ifrm</cfoutput>'])` does it have `parentFormName` key?

Comment: What does `top.frames['<cfoutput>#session.dialogWinId#_ifrm</cfoutput>'].parentFormName;` render as in the HTML? Does `top.frames['theValueOfCFVariable'].parentFormName;` exist in the DOM?